# Direct Link to reach this webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to reach to the **Final State** of my [website](http://clghelp.orgfree.com/) (Link 1) directly using an address that I can enter in the address bar of my browser. I have used a navigation panel which has used a javascript code to change the source of the iframe on clicking on the options.

I have used this code in the navigation panel:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" onmouseleave="closeNav()">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="openNav()" onclick="openNav1()">NA</a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="openNav()" onclick="openNav1()">DBMS</a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="openNav()" onclick="openNav1()">Professional Communication</a>
</div>
<div id="mySidenav1" class="sidenav" onmouseleave="closeNav1()">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav1()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="openNav1()" onclick="gaussSiedel()">Gauss-Siedel</a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="openNav1()" onclick="newtondd()">Newton's Divided Difference</a>
</div>
```

The function gaussSiedel() is:

```
function gaussSiedel() {
  document.getElementById("content").src="http://clghelp.orgfree.com/files/GaussSiedel.html";
}
```

Now I want to give my friend a direct link to the gaussSiedel page (Link 5) but I am unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

The links are given below (I can't post more than two links, so I posted them as code):

```
[Link 1]: http://clghelp.orgfree.com/#
[Step 2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q65aI.jpg
[Step 3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F9kU.jpg
[Final State]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0X3E.jpg
[Link 5]: http://clghelp.orgfree.com/files/GaussSiedel.html
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I just can't get an idea of how to do the task. I want to get a method to directly share a particular state of the website, i.e., with the iframe already having the desired source. Sorry, I didn't mean to offend you @JoeC

Comment: Don't get me wrong; if this were enough to offend me, I would be living a terrible life indeed.  Rather, I was advising you that you'd be unlikely to get an answer to this question as it's currently written, and offered some advice on how to potentially improve it.

Comment: @JoeC is it good now? I mean have I explained it now better?

Comment: use hashes in `href` instead of `onclick` for navigation then listen to hashchange event to change image

Comment: @charlietfl could you please give me an example on how to do it? I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code with

```
<frameset cols=20%,80%>
<frame src="left.html" name="leftside">
<frame src="right.html" name="rightside">
</frameset>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="rightside">Yahoo.com</a>
```

that will simplify some things . And Iframes should not be used this way , instead create new webpage with similar left Menu code and different right side code using divisions .